# SQL: Finding All Currently Used Combinations

Tags: sql, postgresql

Given a many to many table between users and policies structured like the following:

```
policy_id| user_id 
---------|---------
    1    |   1     
    3    |   1     
    6    |   1     
    2    |   2     
    4    |   3     
    6    |   4    
    5    |   5    
    7    |   5
    6    |   7 
    6    |   8
```

I am looking for a list of all the unique combinations of policies that are active/in use by users.

The result I am looking for is:

Active Policy Combinations: [1,3,6], [2], [4], [6], [5,7]

Is this possible in a single query? The only solution I came with involves scanning the entire table and loading each combination into a set filtering out duplicate sets.

**EDIT:**

Answer for the intent and purpose.

I am working on separating out real time processing of the resulting set of policies to the UI we display to the user and caching that information so that we are not constantly recomputing this. For a given set of policies during a given period of time, the user receives a deterministic number of messages.

For instance, if you have policy 1,2,3 - we compute and determine you are to receive messages 2,5. Currently, we are computing/processing this on every single client query. I want to determine all the possible policy combinations so that I can precache the mapping.

Answer (score 0):

You can aggregate twice:

```
select policies, count(*) as num_users
from (select user_id, array_agg(distinct policy_id order by policy_id) as policies
      from t
      group by user_id
     ) u
group by policies;
```

Comment: Giving this a shot - I have 400 million rows in this table; this might take a while (is this a bad idea to run a query like this on such a large table?)

Comment: @PressingOnAlways . . . I don't think you have much choice, given what you are asking to do.

Comment: Is this a bad idea - probably. But with the information you provided there is no alternative. Perhaps if you post what your intent is and what you want to do with the result there may be a better way.

Comment: Updated with intent and what I want to do with the result.